# How do I remove these screws from an IKEA Micke table?

Tags: screws, self-assembly-furniture

I have assembled a Table [Micke](http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/customer_service/assembly/M/M70184091.pdf) for the 1st time ...

but I have some screws I want to remove. or didn't fit well (shld have tighten all screws more), 110126, 103430, 110630

the look like [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfcGo.png)

[image]

they are put in like [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4CnS.png)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Those don't actually screw in.  They just press in the hole and then tighten to the connecting bolt attached to the  opposing piece of wood.  Just loosen the cam so you pull the connecting bolt out.  Should be fairly easy.

After that, if you still need to get the cam part of the fastener out, it should just fall out.  If it doesn't, I just stick a small screwdriver in the connecting bolt hole and lift it up.

Comment: hmm, I am not too familiar with the terms connecting bolt and cam. perhaps its either A or B in **[this image](http://imgur.com/kLdL0.jpg)**? Also as you can see in C, there doesn't appear to be a space for me to use a screwdriver to pry the screw out, I most probably be pushing it deeper?

Comment: A is the cam.  B is the connecting bolt.  You would be using a screwdriver (or anything that fits) through the hole that B is in.  This a perpendicular hole to the cam.

Comment: To clarify what web is saying, while it doesn't technically 'screw in' you do use a screw driver to install and remove it just as if it were a screw.

Answer (score 4):

Finally! after much swearing and screaming it worked! This did it for me!

First make sure that it is not in a locked position (ie remove or lift the bolt attached to the side if any). Then simply screw a screw into the X-area of the fastener from outside, just 1-2 mm so that the screw kind of locks on to the fastener. Then you can wiggle it out.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtUEHMjkl4w

Pro tip: Do not use a screw driver machine or you risk destroying the fastener (as the guy in the video above accidentally does)

Comment: Link only answers become useless when the link goes bad and are frequently confused with spam. Be sure to provide context around the link and quote relevant content in case the link goes bad. See [how to answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: I added a textual description of the solution provided in the video - this solution works great :)

Comment: Worked for me :) tho I also found that if you're just dumping the furniture, brute force helps too!

Answer (score 0):

I've spent ages on these as the plastic slot plug doesn't just pop out with the screw driver. Here's what works:

Turn the plastic plug left or right with a screw driver until you feel that it's loose. (It's not screwed in, but it's like a safe lock - 270 degrees of it blocks the screw it's hidding to make it tight. The remaining 90 degrees when lined up with the screw inside will act as an open door and not be gripping the screw.) Now potentially you may be able to pop out the plastic, but in my case I couldn't.

So on to the second step. I held the adjoining piece of wood (side of shelf) and softly hammered it away from the shelf (with the plugs). Suddenly there was a gap and I could see the metal screws. One side came away with ease, but the other was still caught. So while simultaneously lifting the adjoining wood, I moved the plastic "plus" with a screw driver. Boom! I loosened it and away it came!