# What is type of screw is this?

Tags: screws, furniture, wooden-furniture, bolts

This cylinder-like screw is screwed into an opening on the inside of a table. It basically "locks" into the screw that is facing down from the top.

[image: Screw]

Kind of like this:

[image]

I'm trying to get them out, yet I can't find advice because I don't know the name of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/how-do-i-remove-these-screws-from-an-ikea-micke-table/5736#5736

Comment: http://www.core77.com/posts/27725/death-to-cam-lock-nuts-flatpack-hardware-that-will-hopefully-become-obsolete-27725

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are usually a cam lock assembly. The insert needs to be turned about a half rotation to release it from the cam bolt.

Here is a picture of what one of these things look like.

[image]

Comment: AKA "IKEA Thingamabob"

Comment: Also, the little arrow symbol stamped on the cam-lock (you can see it in the OP's photo) points to the open spot on the cam. So if you're trying to remove it, turn the cam so the arrow is facing the piece you want to remove.

Comment: @DanC -- The stamped in + and - on the cam also help to show which direction to engage/tighten = + and the direction to release/loosen = -.

Answer (score 1):

This Cam Bolt needs to be turned about 90-180 degrees counter-clockwise.

Watch this video: [Click Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQyCkwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D-DfvTQKQtp0&ei=Zs75VNjgBIr0yASkl4LgCw&usg=AFQjCNGJhdgbaEnen8DNpdicdECXJjWytg&sig2=llJVEIRKzus8r_AMDNs37A&bvm=bv.87611401,d.aWw)